# npm Install MySQL package.json Error

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, command

I was trying to install MySQL on my Node.js, and when I typed in `npm install mysql` it says the following. I tried to see if anyone else had the same problem, but it seems like I couldn't find any.

These are the command lines:

```
C:\Users\name>npm install mysql

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\name\package.json'

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\name\package.json'

npm WARN name No description

npm WARN name No repository field.

npm WARN name No README data

npm WARN name No license field.

mysql@2.15.0
updated 1 package in 0.519s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node uses a package.json file to store all the project related information and the dependencies for the project. This makes life much more convenient for anyone who wants to maintain the project.

The error you are getting is that there is no package.json file. Fields inside the file such as description, license, repository etc are unavailable. And hence it throws the warning that you got.

Note that your actual mysql package got installed. What it throws on the terminal are just warnings which you could ignore.

But ideally, you should use

> npm init

to create a package.json file for you. Just use default values if you have to.

Install packages with

> npm install mysql --save

This will save the packages to the package.json file.

Next time when you are running the project on a new computer just run

> npm install

to install all related dependencies for your project.

If this is not a part of a project and you are just playing around with node, you can just ignore the warning and go ahead.

You could use

> npm install mysql -g

to install the package globally.

Also, to check packages that are already installed, use

> npm list

for locally installed packages and

> npm list -g

for globally installed packages

Answer (score 0):

you should first do this

npm init

after that you can install any thing wants

Answer (score 0):

The package.json file stores all the required dependencies and project related information, simplifying the project maintenance.

NPM is unable to detect the desired following fields, provides the essential information about the project. 
    1. Licence
    2. Repositories
    3. Descriptors
    4. Dependencies
    5. Scripts
The information is required to run the server and install new dependencies/libraries.

1. Clear the npm cache
2. Re-initialize or re-generate the Package.json file, by running:

   > npm init
3. Run the command:

   > npm install mysql --save 
   >   Note: Include --save to add the file to your list of dependencies.

To update, use

> npm update